# Rotating objects on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a rather Large project. It was already finished when I started and I have to implement some small gimics.

One of those is the rotation of a marker on a map.

When the marker is selected a rectangle (System.Wndows.FrameWorkElement) is drawn around the picture. Since I would basically have to rewrite the whole program to use another rectangle, I have to stick with the framework element.
To rotate this thing, I added a line and a circle.

The line connects the circle with the rectangle. When the user clicks on the circle and drags the mouse, the whole thing is supposed to rotate around the center of the rectangle.

So far, the rotation of the rectangle and the line works fine. But the circle, though it is rotating around the center of the rectangle, is also rotating around a point at it's own border.
I rotate the rectangle with a RenderTransform object, which works well enough and is easy enough.
For the line and the circle, I wrote a method to calculate the rotation.
The line I can calculate without using the angle.

Here's the method:

```
private void SetPositionOfRotationShaft(Point center)
    {
        double l = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((this.ConnectionLineDirection.X - center.X), 2) + Math.Pow((this.ConnectionLineDirection.Y - center.Y), 2));
        double factor = Math.PI / 180;

        this.connectionLine.X1 = center.X + (this.surroundingRectangle.Height / (2 * l)) * (this.ConnectionLineDirection.X - center.X);
        this.connectionLine.Y1 = center.Y + (this.surroundingRectangle.Height / (2 * l)) * (this.ConnectionLineDirection.Y - center.Y);
        this.connectionLine.X2 = center.X + ((this.surroundingRectangle.Height + 40) / (2 * l)) * (this.ConnectionLineDirection.X - center.X);
        this.connectionLine.Y2 = center.Y + ((this.surroundingRectangle.Height + 40) / (2 * l)) * (this.ConnectionLineDirection.Y - center.Y);

        double translatedLeft = Canvas.GetLeft(this.rotationSign) - center.X;
        double translatedTop = Canvas.GetTop(this.rotationSign) - center.Y;
        double left = ((translatedLeft * Math.Cos(-this.rotateSurroundingRectangle.Angle*factor)) + (translatedTop * Math.Sin(-this.rotateSurroundingRectangle.Angle*factor))) + center.X;
        double top = ((translatedTop * Math.Cos(-this.rotateSurroundingRectangle.Angle * factor)) - (translatedLeft * Math.Sin(-1 * this.rotateSurroundingRectangle.Angle * factor))) + center.Y;
        Canvas.SetLeft(this.rotationSign, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(this.rotationSign, top);
      }
```

Also curious, when i use the same calculation for the line as i do for the circle, the line rotates at a higher speed. The same thing happend to the circle until i added the factor.

Comment: Is this wpf, winforms....?

Comment: No I use System.Windows.Shapes

Comment: I didnt ask the library but your project!

Comment: I'm tempted to say no. But i'm not sure. How can i find that out? I want to say no, since there are no xaml files in the project. Although the program has projects with those.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε It's WPF. The post mentions `System.Windows.FrameworkElement`, which is a WPF class. A proper tag is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was, that i had to set the position of the circle with Canvas.SetLeft() and SetTop(), which is essentialy the upper left corner of a square around the circle.
For my rotation to work, i should have set the center (but that's not possible). So i had to subtract the radius of the circle from top and left.

```
Canvas.SetLeft(this.rotationSign, left-radius);
Canvas.SetTop(this.rotationSign, top-radius);
```